# Left alignment in the algorithm and reset the numbers

Tags: algorithmic

I'm using algorithmic package and I would like to have certain text be left aligned. Also, would like to reset the numbering for each line inside the algorithm after certain text. The MWE provided to illustrate the question:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{amsfonts}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{algorithmic}
 \usepackage{algorithm}
 \usepackage{setspace}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{algorithm}
 \caption{algorithm}
 \begin{spacing}{1}
 \begin{algorithmic}[1]

  % I want the below text to be left 
  % "Some text before the logic:"
   \FOR{ any condition z}
     \STATE apply logic.
   \ENDFOR 

  % I want the below text to be left 
  % "Some text before the logic:"

  % Here I want the numbering to start from 1 again
  \FOR{ any condition x }
    \STATE apply logic.
  \ENDFOR 
  \end{algorithmic}
  \end{spacing}
  \end{algorithm}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry to grumble, but a MWE is a MWE (with emphasis on the "W").  Unless it's something really obvious, it should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.  I can't get yours to work.

Comment: This was part of a very large document. I'm assuming you can put in a document type as long as you include the package. Check the update.

Comment: I included `algorithm`, `algorithmic` and `setspace` but I'm getting an **undefined control sequence** for `\VARIABLES`.

Comment: I have the code running at my machine. Maybe you haven't installed the package. However, to make it run and avoid these undefined control sequence, just delete the `\VARIABLES` and `\text{}` and put for `\COMMENT{Some text before the logic}`. Should work

Comment: Can you confirm that you are using the package `algorithmic` from the [algorithms bundle](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/algorithms/)?  If yes, I don't see how your code compiles.  Inside an `algorithmic` environment, you cannot use free text or paragraph changes.  Your lines must start with commands like `\STATE`, `\FOR`, etc.

Comment: Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I think I figured out the problem. I'm using IEEE class which does  most of the bits that give you error. I have updated the question and it should work now.

Comment: @EngS: If you're using `IEEEtran`, why does your MWE use `article`?

Comment: @Werner I changed the whole MWE to make it work with others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this? You can just completely interrupt the `algorithmic` environment ;)

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{amsfonts}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{algorithmic}
 \usepackage{algorithm}
 \usepackage{setspace}

\newcommand\algotext[1]{\end{algorithmic}#1\begin{algorithmic}[1]}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{algorithm}
 \caption{algorithm}
 \begin{spacing}{1}
 \begin{algorithmic}[1]

  % I want the below text to be left 
  % "Some text before the logic:"
   \FOR{ any condition z}
     \STATE apply logic.
   \ENDFOR 

  % I want the below text to be left 
  \algotext{Some text before the logic:}

  % Here I want the numbering to start from 1 again
  \FOR{ any condition x }
    \STATE apply logic.
  \ENDFOR 
  \end{algorithmic}
  \end{spacing}
  \end{algorithm}
  \end{document}
```